# How do I use a virtualenv to evaluate Python in Light Table?

Tags: python, virtualenv, lighttable

How do I use a virtualenv to evaluate Python in the [Light Table IDE](http://www.lighttable.com)?

I run all my projects under virtualenvs, and all the virtualenvs are located in subfolders within `/.virtualenvs/`(very standard practice)

I see that LightTable supports behaviors on a per-workspace setting, so is there some way to set a behavior that ties a workspace to a particular virtualenv path?

Comment: Looks like support isn't great.  Looks like LT forces automatic interpreter detection on you, so you can't really configure clients/connections manually like you should be able to.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/tIe1h5hzGAs  https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/465

Comment: Thanks @SilasRay - I left a comment on the github issue and based on replies, it sounds like there might be a way, but the syntax is currently undocumented.

Comment: Did you try just activate your virtual environment as usual and start LightTable from it?

Comment: Yes you can do that, but I'd much rather just be able to specify a virtualenv in the settings for a given workspace.

Comment: There's a new issue on Github related to this. https://github.com/LightTable/Python/issues/6

The best workaround seems to be [the activate-then-launch method](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/465#issuecomment-17307055) Alex mentioned above.

Comment: The activate then launch method doesn't work if you want to use multiple projects with different virtual envs though,

Comment: Is this relevant? https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/465

Comment: @PythonNut that issue just links to https://github.com/LightTable/Python/issues/6 as mentioned in a previous comment...

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing as of yet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use LightTable, but if you can tell it to use the python executable in the virtualenv's `bin` directory, that should work.  That's how virtualenv works.  The python executable traverses up through the virtualenv's directory structure until it finds a `lib` dir with the appropriate content.